# modify stroke and fill of svg image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to modify the stroke and fill of an .svg image.
I have been getting some information from [Is it possible to manipulate an SVG document embedded in an HTML doc with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138309/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-an-svg-document-embedded-in-an-html-doc-with-javasc).

I used javascript to manipulate it, the javascript  in the header:

```
function svgMod(){
    var s = document.getElementById("svg_img");
    s.setAttribute("stroke","0000FF");
}
```

the html:

```
...
<body onload="svgMod();">
<img id="svg_img" src="image.svg">  
...
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:1
I think the main problem here is *how to display an svg image as an svg element*, an actual image that instead of an ending like .png or .jpeg, uses an ending of .svg, and furthermore how the fill and stroke of it can then be manipulated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use an img tag then for security reasons you will not be able to access the DOM of the image data. The image is effectively the same as an animated bitmap as far as the container is concerned.

Using an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag will allow you to manipulate the embedded object's DOM.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to understand the problem the OP is having.

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for the response. I used an `<object>` but still It does not change the fill. Javascript: `function svgMod(){
      alert("Fill in blue");
      var circle1 = document.getElementById("svg_image_id");
      circle1.style.fill="blue";
    } ` and HTML: `<object data="waveform.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg_image_id"></object>

  <button onclick=circle1.style.fill="yellow";>Click to change to yellow</button>
  <button onclick=jacascript:svgMod();>Click to change to blue</button>`

Comment: You want something like document.getElementById("svg_image_id").getSVGDocument().getElementById("circle_id").style.fill="blue";

Comment: This method doesn't work so well nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529398/getsvgdocument-returns-null-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: @kev Nowadays is no different. Cross site scripting has never been allowed. If you control both domains CORS enabling might help

Answer (score 10):

I've already answered something like this before, save this snippet as an html file.

```
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
<circle id="circle1" r="30" cx="34" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>
<button onclick=circle1.style.fill="yellow";>Click to change to yellow</button>
```

EDIT: To prove this function can be set in the head, here is a modified version:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function svgMod(){ 
      var circle1 = document.getElementById("circle1"); 
      circle1.style.fill="blue";
    } 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
  <circle id="circle1" r="30" cx="34" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2"/>
  </svg>
  <button onclick=circle1.style.fill="yellow";>Click to change to yellow</button>
  <button onclick=jacascript:svgMod();>Click to change to blue</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried out your solution and it works fine for a circle, but when I try it out with the img attribute it doesn't work!

Comment: first try to replace my circle with the contents of the svg you want to use, if this works you should be able to embed the svg and change it in the same way, i think you can't use the img tag to do this

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to modify the stroke of the individual element, not just the svg element itself. The svg will be composed of a tree of nodes, and it is these nodes which have the stroke attribute.

Comment: Hey Phil, it is an img element not an svg element, it it just that the image is an .svg file.

Comment: Try changing it to an embed: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp then you should be able to manipulate it as part of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the response Phil. I converted the image element to <embed id="svg_img" src="svg_img.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> but the result is the same.

Comment: Looks like it can only be modified if an actual svg tag, then. Can you include the contents of the svg inline in the html file?

Comment: This is the inline stuff I am writing: `<svg id="another_id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
  <embed id ="svg_image_id" src="waveform.svg" height="300px;" width="100%" type="image/svg+xml"/>
  </svg>
  `

Comment: Sorry, I mean actually serve the contents of the svg inline in the html file, not via an embed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10044/discussion-between-potney-switters-and-phil-h)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this has been resolved. I had experienced a similar scenario and the best way is to put the svg file in an `<bject>` tag and change the stroke property not fill property.

```
svgItem.style.stroke="lime";
```

Also you may refer to the section: Changing CSS Properties of SVG in this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/scripting.html)

I had tested this and could change the stroke property. Please refer to this [screnshot](https://ibin.co/35M78Z6Ex0p1.png) and below is the sample code which worked for me.

```js
window.onload=function() {
 // Get the Object by ID
 var a = document.getElementById("svgObject");
 // Get the SVG document inside the Object tag
 var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
 // Get one of the SVG items by ID;
 var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("pin1");
 // Set the colour to something else
 svgItem.style.stroke ="lime";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **simple** example that demonstrates modifying an attribute of an SVG HTML object using javascript:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <rect id="A1" x="10" y="10" width="25" height="25" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </body>

  <script>
    alert("Acknowledge to modify object color.");
    var object = document.getElementById("A1");
    object.setAttribute("fill", "green");
  </script>
</html>
```