# How can I change the color of an SVG image on hover?

Tags: html, css, javascript, svg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing SVG image color with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)

I'd like to change the fill of an SVG image when I hover over it.

Right now I have a black question mark exported from Illustrator to SVG.
I can put on my page with the img tag and it displays fine, however I have no idea how to change the color in code.

Comment: I am not too familiar with SVGs, maybe you can change the background-color on hover? I did something like this for an assignment a while ago: http://bit.ly/Q1Irwv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG Files can be modified directly from javascript, i.e. properties of the "image" are accessible from within the DOM.

Look at this post from stack overflow: [modify stroke and fill of svg image with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139460/modify-stroke-and-fill-of-svg-image-with-javascript)

It's important to remember that to do so, you cannot enclose the svg file in the common HTML <*img/>* tag, use instead the <*svg>*...*<*/svg> as shown in the post.

EDIT: [svg on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_examples.asp)

I added a link to w3schools so you can see more properties of the svg object

Have Fun

Comment: the svg on w3schools gives 404 (page not found).

Comment: The Link has been updated

Answer (score 7):

If you need to do hover effects in svg you shouldn't use <img> tags. Instead reference the svg with an <iframe>, <object> or <embed> tag. If you want to save a http GET request you can put the svg markup inline in the html document.

Here's an example showing a simple fill hover effect [inside an svg](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/hover-change-fill.svg), and [another one](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/transparent-images-pointer-events.svg) (slightly more complex that creates an outline on hover using a filter). Anyway, it's basically about applying a :hover CSS rule to set the fill color.

An example with all of the above ways of using svg can be seen [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/hover-change-fill-multi-reference.html).

Answer (score -2):

If you can post your code, maybe we can troubleshoot it for you.

Try following this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html

Alternatively (not exclusive to SVG), use this type of code with different images:

```
<img src="image1.svg"
onmouseover="this.src='image2.svg'"
onmouseout="this.src='image1.svg'">
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JNChw/

Comment: image replacement is a very ineffecient way to change a hover fill color (for the svg case).