# Change the color of one svg element from html img tag - css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an svg I am loading in html, which looks like this:

```
<img src="assets/img/big_layout.svg" alt="Line Overview" class="line_overview">
```

the actual svg file looks like this:

```
<svg x="0" y="0" width="1466" height="825" viewBox="0 0 1466 825" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
<defs>
<!-- SOME STYLES I've REMOVED -->
</defs>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0,0L1466,0l0,825L0,825L0,0Z" class="g1_1" />
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0,0L1466,0l0,825L0,825L0,0Z" class="g1_1" />
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M187,21l195,0l0,195l-195,0L187,21Z" 
// LOADS MORE PATHS!!!!
```

I would like to be able to change some of the styles in this svg from the parent html, e.g. add a `fill: green` to the `.g1_1` class. Is this possible?

Comment: Could this maybe help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139460/modify-stroke-and-fill-of-svg-image-with-javascript#10141550

Comment: There is actually [an hack](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/5198257) that involves the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector and different CSS rules set inside the svg itself. You then just have to change the url's hash identifier to some defined element (`myFile.svg#myBlueGroup`  /  `myFile.svg#myRedGroup`), but this is just a hack so doesn't worth your question to be reopened, and doesn't answer the dupe (cc @PaulLeBeau)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to load the svg in the markup then you can do the following:

```
<html>
...
<svg></svg>
...
</html>
```

And then style it via CSS:

```
svg .g1_1 {
  fill: green;
}
```

An example:

```css
svg {
  width: 64px;
}

svg polygon {
  fill: red;
}

svg:hover polygon {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
  <g> 
    <polygon fill="none" points="18,4 10,12 22,24 10,36 18,44 38,24 "></polygon> 
  </g>
</svg>
```