# Animating minor details with vector imagery for the web

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am wondering if there is a way to animate a vector object for modern web. My example is a cartoony squid outline and I want to animate its tentacles to be wiggling. My goal is to find a way to do this and not use Flash and hopefully have mobile support. I am okay if it only works in the most modern browsers as well as it is more of a 'fun extra' exploration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Vector based graphics in web translates to SVG. Try googling the term "SVG Javascript".

Here's a similar question:

[Is it possible to manipulate an SVG document embedded in an HTML doc with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138309/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-an-svg-document-embedded-in-an-html-doc-with-javasc)